# matlab fixed point iteration jumping down to zero after stabilizing at fixed point

Tags: matlab

When I apply the simple loop;

```
for i =1:50


B(i+1)=1/2*(B(i)+(9/B(i)))


end
```

My list gives me the right answer $3$ but then after a a few iterates it jumps down to zero. Does anyone know what that is about?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with initial values of `B` equal to 1, 2, and 10. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces the output you're seeing.

Comment: The only way I can imagine is that the array B is longer than 51 elements and elements after index 51 were initially set to zero.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia aah right I must have missed that when I changed 
 amout of elements.